# When to use JWT

Tags: jwt, stateless

Since JWT is self-contained, it can be used for stateless authentication. If we want to revoke the token, then we need to lookup somewhere, in database, in memcache. But that is against stateless.

So, JWT can be used only when we need stateless and don't need to revoke the token?

Answer (score 3):

Well you could update a user record in your database to prohibit someone from logging in entirely (and thus tell your app to ignore the user's tokens), but I don't think there's a way of revoking individual tokens from a user (unless you gave your tokens individual IDs and stored the IDs in your database--but as you point out, that kinda seems like it would largely defeat the point of JWT's).

**Update**

This article talks about JWT revocation (as well as links to some other sources):
https://dadario.com.br/revoking-json-web-tokens/

Comment: "I don’t see the point in Revoking or Blacklisting JWT" – This post sums it up pretty well: https://www.dinochiesa.net/?p=1388